# How to call a Excel VBA procedure through late binding

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a bit of advice here.

I have a spreadsheet with various modules and procedures that can be called from a Worksheet_Change event.  This causes problems when I need to issue a sheet from the workbook for other users to complete.

Whenever the user tries to update the sheet, the on change event gets triggered, causing a compile error as the procedure being called does not exist, and this cannot be trapped (as far as I'm aware). I've tried using Application.EnableEvents = False, but this is in the worksheet event and the code breaks as soon as the event is triggered.

Is there anyway to call a procedure through late binding where I can trap the error?

I'm trying something like this at the moment.

```
Dim mdl as object

' Test for module in workbook, if error, then exit routine
Set mdl = Application.ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("mdlSharedFunctions")

'If no error, then call procedure here
call mdl.UpdateData(Target)

'Or
Application.Run mdl.UpdateData(Target)
```

Neither of these call methods will work and I'm hoping someone out there will be able to point me in the right direction.

Cheers

Pete

Comment: I can suggest the use of some flags there... In which cases do you want the procedure to be called, in in which not?

Comment: Late binding is using IDispatch (basically client says do you support com function Print, server replies it's fuction 10, client says do function 10). Only class modules are COM objects. So only class modules can be bound. Perhaps you can use `CallByName` Function
      

Executes a method of an object, or sets or returns a property of an object.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the reply. I'm not sure if you can use flags in excel? If so, this is something that I know nothing about. I've used the call by name Call mdlSharedFunctions.UpdateData(Target) which works, when in the parent workbook, but still causes the compile error in the new lifted sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global variable as a flag - bit dirty but it works fine. Then add an `If flag = true then` statement to the change event sub.

```
Public globalflag as Boolean

Sub test1()

If globalflag = True Then
    BrokenSub 'This sub has an invalid sub/function referenced, but will be ignored if the flag is set to false
Else
    'Don't run the code
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub

Sub BrokenSub()
invalidfunction ("asb")
End Sub
```

EDIT

To put it in a worksheet, just see if the variable exists:

Declare this in a module in your master spreadsheet:

```
Public globalflag as Boolean
```

Then in your worksheet code

```
If not IsEmpty(globalflag) Then
    BrokenSub 'Put your master spreadsheet code here - it'll run if globalflag exists and be ignored if it doesn't
End If

Sub BrokenSub()
invalidfunction ("asb")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks MattCrum,
How would I go about setting this up in the worksheet?  At the moment, each worksheet has a call to a procedure stored in a module, which then performs various operations.  When I lift the worksheets out to send for completion, the module is not included, so when the change event is triggered, the compiler automatically sees the call to the missing procedure and throws up a compile error before any code is run.